# useContext triggers rerendering without changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context, react-usememo

I have following `react`-component:

```
type Props = {
    country: string;
    electricityValues: number[];
    activeStep: number;
    setActiveStep: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
}

const EmissionsMemoized = (props: Props) => {
    const {country, electricityValues, activeStep, setActiveStep} = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        //make api call
    }, [electricityValues]);

    return (
        <>
            //...
        </>
    );
}
```

To avoid unnecessary rerender, I have `memo`ized it like following:

```
export default function Emissions() {
    const {country, electricityValues, activeStep, setActiveStep} = useContext(AppContext);
    return useMemo(() => (<EmissionsMemoized country={country} electricityValues={electricityValues} activeStep={activeStep} setActiveStep={setActiveStep} />), []);
}
```

The component is being served in a `Stepper`-Component:

```
function getStepContent(step: number) {
    switch (step) {
//...
        case 2:
            return <Emissions />;
//...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `useEffect()` is getting triggered, making an API-call every time the `Emissions`-component is being returned by `getStepContent()`, regardless if state actually changed.

Any idea how to make `useEffect()` trigger only if value of `electricityValues`-array changes?

Is it because `useContext()` is returning a new reference every time?

Comment: Move the useContext within the EmissionsMemoized. I think it is happening because you are unmounting and mounting the component with the stepper code.

Comment: Good idea. Moving useContext withing EmissionsMemoized had no effect though :-( Then I tried memoizing the Emissions-Component from within getStepContent() as in case 1:
                return useMemo(() => (<CountryForm />), [country, electricityValues]);
When stepping through, React complained about different number of hooks, so I had to memoize all the steps with the opposite effect and now it's always same component being returned by getStepContent.